# How does non-linearity (S-box) add security to AES?

Tags: aes, s-boxes, linear-cryptanalysis

I'm trying to understand how AES guarentees security. One of the named points on the web is that AES uses a non-linear step (the *SubBytes step*). But how exactly does the Rijndael key schedule add security? It sounds like a wide question, but for me, not exactly an expert, it's hard to understand.

*Help is appreciated*

Comment: The title asks how **non-linearity (S-box)** adds security. The body of the question adds how **the Rijndael key schedule** adds security. Please clarify what's asked. Do you understand how, regardless of the key schedule's output, non-linearity is essential for security of AES?

Comment: I said that because the non-linearity (S-box) is part of the Rijndael key schedule. No, I don't understand.

Comment: The non-linearity is also, and foremost, part of the encryption itself. In the formal specification of AES by NIST, [FIPS 197](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf), SubBytes is not even part of the key schedule (the corresponding non-linear operation is called SubWord). Hint to answer your own question without the _key schedule_ part of it: assume that a function $f$ is said to be linear iff $\forall (x,y,z), f(x\oplus y\oplus z)=f(x)\oplus f(y)\oplus f(z)$. What can you say about the [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) of linear functions?

Comment: @fgrieu Even without the ambiguous context I find the question of how the key schedule adds security to be quite ironical given that the key schedule appears to be the weakest part of AES.

Answer (score -2):

actually in most of methods like AES,DES have two important phenomena ,one is confusion and other is diffusion.so in whole process only Sbyte step bring confusion(brings non-linearity) while in diffusion data is just misplaced not changed.